# OpenCV undefined reference to `cv::cvtColor while building with CMake

Tags: c++, opencv, cmake, linker, undefined-reference

I am building a basic edge detector with OpenCV. I can compile it with g++ and results are also as expected. But I need to build this using CMake and for the below mentioned CMakeListst.txt I am getting the error:

```
undefined reference to cv::cvtColor
```

and almost all the methods in *cv* namespace.

My code compiles well with

```
g++ -std=c++14 /home/dave/test_edge.cpp -o output `pkg-config opencv4 --cflags --libs`
```

but following CMake gives the error

CMakeLIsts.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)

project(Project)

find_package(OpenCV 4 REQUIRED)


include_directories(${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS})
add_executable(output src/EdgeDetector.cpp)
target_include_directories(output PRIVATE include)
target_link_libraries(output ${OpenCV_LIBS})
MESSAGE("OpenCV_LIBS: " ${OpenCV_LIBS} )
```

The MESSAGE output is:

```
OpenCV_LIBS: opencv_calib3dopencv_coreopencv_dnnopencv_features2dopencv_flannopencv_gapiopencv_highguiopencv_imgcodecsopencv_imgprocopencv_mlopencv_objdetectopencv_photoopencv_stitchingopencv_videoopencv_videoio
```

I understand the issue is with linking but I have arrived at a saturation point. I am a bit new to CMake and still learning, any help is appreciated.

Comment: Hint: When output a list in CMake, put that list into double quotes: `MESSAGE("OpenCV_LIBS: ${OpenCV_LIBS} ") `. That way CMake will delimit list elements with semicolon. You may also compare output of the `${OpenCV_LIBS}` with output of `pkg-config opencv4 --cflags --libs` which you use in successful command-line invocation.

Comment: if you installed with `OPENCV_GENERATE_PKGCONFIG` what is the output of `pkg-config --modversion opencv` or `pkg-config --modversion opencv4`

Comment: @YunusTemurlenk pkg-config --modversion opencv4 shows 4.7.0